# Can't create table in h2 database Spring Boot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, h2

So, I just want to create simple table of Person in the database.

Here is my Code:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonTable")
public class Person {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private long id;
 private String name;
 private int age;

}
```

However When I run the application and go to h2-console, there is no table created:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYVvf.png)

Here is application.properties: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxN7A.png)

What am I doing wrong? How can i create a simple table in the h2 database?

P.S The program works fine, I have added dependencies lombok, JPA, H2, Spring Web

Comment: You can enable sql log and check if tables are created or not. set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`. What is the value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`?

Comment: Please post your `application.properties` to see the relevant database entries.

Comment: I posted app.properties (edited the post)

Comment: Always post code as text not images, whenever possible it's the recommended form.

Comment: Not images please! Post your logs and your application.properties by copying them and pasting as code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

So, The reason that it didn't created a table was because I have created a new package for person, which was not in the com.example.demo package, so in a word you should put all your code in the same package as your main.